# JCombobox.setVisible(false);

Tags: java, swing, visibility, jcombobox

Even though it's a valid method, `JComboBox#setVisible` doesn't hide my `JComboBox`. Am I doing something wrong? If not, are there any alternatives?

Comment: *"Am I doing something wrong?"*  Yes.  For better (or any) help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: That method works as expected

Comment: _Ecce vis de [sscce](http://sscce.org/) infra!_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't show any interest in posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), here is mine showing that what you stated in question is false and nothing can be done until you post your code.

This works fine for me ,

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class FrameTest extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JComboBox test;

    public FrameTest() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(550, 100);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton hideJCombo = new JButton("Hide my JCombobox!");
        JButton showJCombo = new JButton("Show my JCombobox!");

        String course[] = {"This", "is", "a", "sample", "for", "StackOverflow"};
        test = new JComboBox(course);

        add(hideJCombo);
        add(test);
        add(showJCombo);


        hideJCombo.setActionCommand("hide");
        showJCombo.setActionCommand("show");

        hideJCombo.addActionListener(this);
        showJCombo.addActionListener(this);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new FrameTest().setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if ("hide".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            test.setVisible(false);
            System.out.println("hide");
        } else if ("show".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            test.setVisible(true);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not even sure why I spent time on creating the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), but this code just works as expected. I suggest you compare it with your code and search for differences

```
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

public class ComboboxDemo {
  private static JFrame createFrame(){
    JFrame result = new JFrame( "ComboboxDemo" );

    final JComboBox<String> combobox = createCombobox();
    result.add( combobox, BorderLayout.CENTER );

    JCheckBox toggleVisibility = new JCheckBox( "Toggle visibility" );
    toggleVisibility.setSelected( combobox.isVisible() );
    toggleVisibility.addItemListener( new ItemListener() {
      @Override
      public void itemStateChanged( ItemEvent e ) {
        combobox.setVisible( e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED );
      }
    } );
    result.add( toggleVisibility, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

    result.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    result.pack();
    return result;
  }

  private static JComboBox<String> createCombobox(){
    return new JComboBox<>( new String[]{"foo", "bar", "StackOverflow", "Hello World"} );
  }

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        createFrame().setVisible( true );
      }
    } );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No one can answer to your question until you post the code. However, for the question of "Alternatives", I will answer.

1. You can disable it using "setEnabled(false)"
2. If it is inside a JPanel, you can remove it using "remove()" method and other overloaded versions of that method
3. You might be able to use "setEditable(false)" to set it non editable. I haven't tried it yet anyway